# What is faster to calculate: Large looped calculations or Vlookup on multiple large data grids?

Tags: vba, matlab, excel, conceptual

This is a **conceptual** question that will help me before I start coding my next project. Which approach do you think will be faster?

**Loop Calculations**: An example of how it would be set up:

```vb
for i = 0 to 67
    While x < 350
        y = 0
        While y < 600
            Call solved() 'solves and returns "concentration"
            If c(y, x) <> Empty = True Then
            c(y, x) = c(row, x) + concentration
            Else
            c(y, x) = concentration
            End If
            y = y + 1
        Wend
        x = x + 1
    Wend
Next i
```

**Vlookup**:
Using Matlab I can generate millions of solved data points and store them into a matrix. This can be stored in a database.

**Restrictions**: Only Access available as a database. and with the amount of data needed to be stored it will hit memory limit. Excel is not a good idea to store this much data as well.

Taking the restriction into account, I have thought of using multiple text files to store data and use Excel to search and pull values.

**Theoretically,** a search should be faster. But with different files to open up and a large matrix to look through, the speed will be affected. What do you guys think, and please input if there is a better approach. Thanks!

Comment: the loop example is not entirely accurate, it shows the magnitude of calculations that I will be doing. 'i' will iterate through an array of values and x will be reset to a value as well.

Comment: For huge data, definitely a database, with an index on the columns you want to search. Also use precompiled queries.

Comment: Definitely use a database. You could consider using SQLite or SQL Server Express as a local database store. SQLite there is basically no size restriction, I think SQL Server Express is 10GB.

Comment: Using a text file to store data is ok if you have **[PowerPivot for Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210599(v=sql.110).aspx)** installed. It overcomes million rows limit.

Comment: If you have access to MATLAB, why don't you use that to handle everything, rather than using it to do calculations and then leaning on VBA?

Comment: @Wolfie Unfortunately, I am restricted to what is already installed on the computers. Microsoft Office is what is most available to me.

Comment: Okay, you should realise that you haven't actually said anywhere in your question *what* you're trying to do, just the best way to do it... Without knowing what you're trying to do it is hard to help